# Passport js login from cross-domain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, cross-domain

How can a user login from another domain. Ex. Main site has login form, and ajax posts to a route on my nodejs server.

```
// submit form to node server(app) FROM WEBSITE
$('#submit-project-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3100/login",
        data: formData,
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            var success =  $($.parseHTML(response.responseText)).filter("body"); 
            console.log(response.responseText);
        }
     }); 

});

// Passport POST auth methods. Listen to POST route from website
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/', // re-run user.index which should pass as a user and render profile
    failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true
}));
```

This triggers the route, and I am getting the email and password needed to login for my passport strategy.

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
    console.log(req.body.email); // returns email entered in cross-domain field
    console.log(email); // returns email entered in cross-domain field
    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    AppUser.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
        if (err)
            return done(err);

        // if no user is found, return the message
        if (!user)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

        // if the user is found but the password is wrong
        if (!user.validPassword(password))
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

        // all is well, return successful user
        return done(null, user); 

    });

}));
```

CORS is enabled on the nodejs server, it works because I am able to submit payments cross-domain, and I get a response from the server.

I think the problem is passport has `successRedirect` and somewhere with that lies the issue, I may need a custom success function? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `xhrFields` added to the ajax made it work. I'll continue to test, but I was able to login with a cross-domain POST, pretty cool.

```
xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true
},
```